# How to place document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(metatag); on top of the head tag

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, meta-tags, ghost-blog, prerender

I have a SPA (single page app) and use prerender.io to cache the page for search bots. I generate my meta tags on the fly from my proxy api with this code, example for description and og.description:

```
var decriptionmetatag = document.createElement('meta');  
decriptionmetatag.setAttribute('name', 'description');  
decriptionmetatag.content = description.innerText;  
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(decriptionmetatag);
                
var ogdecriptionmetatag = document.createElement('meta');  
ogdecriptionmetatag.setAttribute('property', 'og.description');  
ogdecriptionmetatag.content = description.innerText;  
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(ogdecriptionmetatag);
```

But my ghost cms has also meta-tags who come before the one I generate. Is there a way to place the result of the javascript code on top of the head or to overrule the standard meta-tags.

Comment: `.prepend()` will add element in front of all content. Also, `.prepend()` and `.append()` allows more than one parameter (ex. `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].append(ogdecriptionmetatag, decriptionmetatag);`)

Comment: Yes it works with .prepend() thank you!

Answer (score 0):

.prepend() is the answer tnx @zer00ne

```
var ogdecriptionmetatag = document.createElement('meta');  
ogdecriptionmetatag.setAttribute('property', 'og.description');  
ogdecriptionmetatag.content = description.innerText;  
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].prepend(ogdecriptionmetatag);
```